# In Unity change color of the editor during Play Mode

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I was watching some tutorials in Unity and when the guy press Play to run and test his game, the editor changes to red color. I think that is very cool because sometimes I forget that I am in Play Mode and do some changes that are gone once I stop the Play Mode, and I need to repeat them.

Does any one know how to change the color of Unity during Play Mode?

Thank you!!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For **Windows** you have to go to Edit -> Preferences -> Colors -> Play Mode tint

[image]

[image]

And in case you work with **MAC**, it will be:

Unity -> Prefernces -> Colors -> Play Mode tint

Here is a video about it:

https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/tips/play-mode-editor-tint

Comment: I'm afraid Hellium beat you to it by a couple of seconds

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer haha yeah, I was looking for the screen shots

Answer (score 8):

Go to `Edit > Preferences > Color` and change the `Playmode Tint`

[image]